# Typescript generic utility type

Tags: typescript

Is there any utility type in TS to help me get generic type?

I'm looking for something like `GenericType`

```
const foo = ['foo']
type MyStringType = GenericType<typeof foo> // equal to type MyStringType = string


let bar : Promise<number>
type MyNumberType = GenericType<typeof bar> // equal to type MyNumberType = number
```

I am using `jest-axe` and in `let  results: axe.AxeResults;` I have `TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'axe'.` error, Also I cannot import `AxeResults`
I want to use `GenericType<ReturnType<typeof axe>>`

[image]

[image]

Comment: To extract types from other types, use `infer`: https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-infer-typescript/

Comment: What does  `Cannot find namespace 'axe'` have to do with your question about utility types?

Comment: see screenshots

Answer (score -1):

Generic types are usually represented by letters in typescript as in Array<T,U>. Also the most generic type in typescript is `any`.